# snort intrusion detection

Tags: security, networking, ids, snort

Hi im trying to use snort as an IDS on some pcap files I have, I was hoping I would get a log of any intrusions. I know for a fact that there is port scans and ping sweeps etc in the pcap files but when I try this command:

**C:\Snort\bin>** `snort -r c:\snort\log\trace_part01.pcap -l c:\snort\log -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -K ascii`

Nothing happens, I can log the the data like so:

```
snort -r c:\snort\log\trace_part01.pcap -l c:\snort\log -K ascii
```

Which structures all the files in there relevant ip folders and they have .ids as an extension.

Im new to using snort so not quite sure how I can just detect what intrusions are in the pcap files and output them in a file.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault

Comment: Can anyone migrate?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is with your snort.conf file.

Have you got the following line

```
include $PREPROC_RULE_PATH/preprocessor.rules
```

uncommented? If not, uncomment the rule to enable it and try again forcing Snort to re-read the configuration file.

You may also need to ensure the following line in `snort.conf` is set to high but I'm not 100% sure that it'd be necessary -

```
preprocessor sfportscan: proto { all } memcap { 1000000 } sense_level { high } scan_type { all }
```